# My ethernet is not been detected in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, internet

I'm very new to Ubuntu, all of a sudden my internet is not working in my Ubuntu machine.

But fortunately the internet is working in my Windows machine. The ethernet cable is not even gets detected in my Ubuntu machine.

As a new user to Ubuntu, this is really frustrating. Are there any ways to use internet in Ubuntu?

#### Edit:

Doing `ifconfig eth0`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:f0:49:c4:7f:2d  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:42
```

Doing `lspci` , gives me :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset DRAM Controller (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 01)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev e1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation N10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 01)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 01)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 02)
```

In my windows machine I have the config like this:

[image]

I'm new to Ubuntu, I need some help in setting up my internet connection!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Salem: I have edited my question.

Comment: Let me guess... you have a "Realtek" gigabit onboard?

Comment: @TardisGuy `02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 02)` suggests that ;)

Comment: @TardisGuy: Yes.

Answer (score 3):

Yep... you need a driver. The best plan is to get the driver on your windows machine, then boot to linux and compile it. You can follow the steps found in [this guide at the Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1992200):

1. [Download the driver](http://www.realtek.com.tw/DOWNLOADS/downloadsView.aspx?LANGID=1&PNID=13&PFID=5&LEVEL=5&CONN=4&DOWNTYPEID=3&GETDOWN=FALSE) and expand it into a new directory. `cd` to the
   top directory in the expanded directory.
2. `sudo make clean modules`
3. `sudo make install`
4. Verify that a new file named `r8168.ko` exists in the directory
   `/lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek/`.
5. blacklist r8169.
6. Edit `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` and add a line with "r8168" in it.
7. `sudo depmod -a`
8. `sudo update-initramfs -v -u -k`  `uname -r`
9. Reboot

Comment: Should you still need internet in Ubuntu before the driver is in; My method is tethering my android via usb.

Comment: Its only 68KB. How do I install it?

Comment: This too doesn't worked for me!! :(

Comment: It has been quite some time since this answer...but just helped me now and saved a valuable day!!! Thanks @TardisGuy :)

Answer (score 3):

Ok it seems that your network card is recognized, so it should be a problem with your network. Try those steps:

```
sudo dhclient eth0
```

Check if you have internet now (without closing the terminal window). If it works you should create a new Wired connection in Network Manager(with Method as "Authomatic (DHCP)").

If you still dont have internet you should inspect your Windows network configuration. Probably you have a fixed IP address that you can gather from there, and supply it to Network Manager.

### Edit

Looking at your configuration it seems your network is configured using DHCP. So, go to Network Manager, delete any Wired network you could have there, and create a new one.
[image]

Then select DHCP in IPv4 tab:

[image]

After that try to connect manually through the newly created connection. If it still don't work try to select "Automatic (DHCP) addresses only" (step 3) and add the information "DNS servers" you got in the Windows screenshot.

Comment: I have updated my question, Can you say me how to supply the IP to my network manager?

Comment: Have you tried the dhclient command? It worked (you could access the internet)? And btw you have two systems installed or one of your systems is a virtual machine?

Comment: I runned the command : `sudo dhclient eth0` in my terminal, I didn't see any error or output only the blank screen for long time. But couldn't able to access internet. I have dual OS. Not virtual machines.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I have added the network and I have clicked on `save`. But however I couldn't able to see my new network connection!

Answer (score -1):

This is as a bug in Ubuntu 12.0.4 (bug: [#145382 | broken 70-persistent-net.rules](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465801/ubuntu-server-12-0-4-x86-not-detecting-network-adapter-on-virtualbox-4-3))

**The fix is:**

1. look into your settings what is your NIC MAC address and remember it > $MAC
2. `nano /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`
3. Look up for:

   > SUBSYSTEM=="net", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTRS{address}=="**$MAC**",
   >   NAME="eth5"
4. Rename it as `NAME='eth0'`
5. Make sure your `/etc/network/interfaces` is correct
6. Reboot

Comment: Please provide a digest of this solution, answers should no simply rely on links.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa done. I thought it will be just a copy that's why I only provided a link!

Comment: If you think this question has already been asked you can flag it as a duplicate.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa well technically it is not identical .. but the solution is. So I am going to keep it.