# Ubuntu server 12.0.4 x86 not detecting network adapter on virtualbox 4.3

Tags: 12.04, server, intel

This is the output of `lspic -nn`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma] (rev 02)
00:01.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 ISA [Natoma/Triton II]
00:01.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE (rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter
00:03.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
00:04.0 System peripheral: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Guest Service
00:05.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801AA AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 01)
**00:07.0 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 08)**
00:0d.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 02)
```

While obviously my Ethernet is detected in the above output. It is not on `ifconfig` list.
here is the output of `ifconfig`:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~$ ifconfig

lo Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric:1
RX packets:70 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:70 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
RX bytes:6939 (6.9 KB) TX bytes:6939 (6.9 KB)
```

Even if I try `ifconfig eth0 up` - I get an error:

> eth0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device

Comment: You may have better luck on the Virtualbox forums. Also your images do not really explain what your problem is, it appears NAT is working. Please describe your problem in more detail.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I actually found a solution - but I can't post it due to reputation restriction so I am waiting for the 8 hours constraint and I will put the answer :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some googling I found this is as a bug in Ubuntu 12.0.4 (bug: [#145382 broken 70-persistent-net.rules](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udev/+bug/145382))

**The fix is:**

1. look into your settings what is your NIC MAC address and remember it > $MAC
2. `nano /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`
3. Look up for:

> SUBSYSTEM=="net", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTRS{address}=="**$MAC**",
>   NAME="eth5"
>
> Rename it as `NAME='eth0'`
>
> Make sure your `/etc/network/interfaces` is correct
>
> Reboot